# Does Liquibase have a mechanism to update/refresh Views when changes are made to the referenced Tables?

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

In my scenario there are a significant amount of Views that are being managed. A column change to a single table may result in dozens to hundreds of Views needing adjustment. If we are creating new changesets to accommodate updates to each View, this can get unwieldily quite fast.

Many of these Views are also replicated across multiple schemas, meaning that there are essentially identical changesets for each View being created per schema.

How can this be managed without having to edit every single changeset per View, or creating dozens to hundreds of new Views?

Using `runOnChange=true` or `runAlways=true` on the createView changeset would allow editing the original Views, but this could mean hundreds of edits per incremental table change.

Is there a better way to manage this?

Comment: Just drop all views before doing anything else, then simply re-create all of them at the end.

Comment: I may not have made this clear, but the views reference the tables and specific columns, if a column is added to the referenced table, each view that is missing it will need to be manually updated by adding the column.

I'm trying to avoid having to edit hundreds of views for a single table change.